# scala - Cannot override protected variable of java class

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to override a Java class that looks somewhat like this

```
public class ExampleJava {
  public ExampleJava(String string) {

  }

  protected String string;
}
```

When I use

```
class ExampleScala(string : String) {
  @Override
  protected override def string : String
}
```

in Scala, the compiler gives the error:

```
Error:(5, 7) overriding method string in class ExampleScala of type => 
java.lang.String;
variable string in class ExampleJava of type net.java.lang.String has incompatible    
type;
(Note that method string in class ExampleJava of type => java.lang.String is 
abstract,
and is therefore overridden by concrete variable string in class ExampleJava of type 
java.lang.String)
class ExampleScala(material : Material) extends ExampleJava(string : String) {
  ^
```

**UPDATE:** I can't modify ExampleJava as it is in a program being extended and if this was released it would not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't use `@Override` in Scala; only the Java compiler is aware about it. In Scala `override` is used instead.
2. `protected String string;` in `ExampleJava` is a field, so it can't be overridden at all. If you want it to be overridable, you need to write

   ```
   private String string;

   protected String string() {
       return string;
   }
   ```

instead. You'll also need an actual implementation in `ExampleScala`.

Comment: Any way to do something like that without changing ExampleJava? I can't preform modifications to ExampleJava as it is in a program being extended and if this was released it would not work.

Comment: No, there is no way to override fields at all. What do you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot [`@Override`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) field member, you can only override methods, It is just an annotation that makes sure at compile time weather you are really overriding method or not

> Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method declaration in a superclass. If a method is annotated with this annotation type but does not override a superclass method, compilers are required to generate an error message.

Comment: It still happens with no @Override